# use httpclient4.0.3.jar in eclipse but import error

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-7, httpclient

I put httpclient-4.0.3.jar, httpcore-4.0.1.jar under the lib folder in eclipse. I use them in Java Build Path > Libraries. But I still get error in my java source file, cannot import classes in these jars.

My OS is window7
Java Run-time Environment is 1.6_0_45
eclipse is 3.7

I have cleaned and refresh the project to rebuild it a couple of times. it does not work. 
my computer is just upgraded from windows XP. it used to be OK before the upgrade.

how can i make it right?

Comment: the error classes are in org.apache.commons.httpclient package

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.FileRequestEntity;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.RequestEntity;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.StringRequestEntity;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.ByteArrayRequestEntity;

Comment: Can you look into the libraries and make sure that the erroneous imported classes are really in the jars? Maybe you're missing another library. Otherwise, your description sounds correct.

Comment: i just checked. yes they are not in httpcore.jar nor httpclient.jar. do you know which jar these classes should be in?

Comment: Check my answer! Try an older version of the libraries. Check which ones you were using before.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the httpclient library renamed/moved classes and packages.

According to [this site](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.apache.commons.httpclient.NameValuePair), the last httpclient version that contains `org.apache.commons.httpclient.NameValuePair` is 3.1-alpha1.

If you take a look at the [api from httpclient 4.2.5](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html), you see that the package structure is different. HttpClient is now in package `org.apache.http.client` instead of `org.apache.httpclient`.

I would recommend that you get the version of your libraries that you have been using before, which, most likely, was not the 4.0.3 or 4.0.1 that you are currently using.

Comment: thanks. i includes commons-httpclient-3.1.jar. it is fine now